# Question About Fantasy Novels By F.J. Hale/Robert E. Vardeman

Tags: robert-e-vardeman

A long time ago (late 1980's) I read the following books by F.J. Hale:
Ogre Castle
In the Sea Nymph's Lair

It doesn't seem like the series was ever finished.  I remember reading in one of the books that F.J. Hale was the pseudonym for another well known author.  I recently found out that Robert E. Vardeman is another name for the same author.

Does anyone know why he used a different pen name or why the series was never finished?  Are there any other names this author published under?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_E._Vardeman#Pseudonyms

Comment: According to the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1014) he used these names: Victor Appleton, Edward George, F. J. Hale, Edward S. Hudson, Daniel Moran, Bob Vardeman, Robert Vardeman, Robert E. Vardeman.

Comment: Wow.  He published under a lot of names.  So it doesn't seem like using a different name for this particular series was anything unusual for him.  So I guess the only part of the question remaining is whether anyone knows why the series was never completed.  With the additional info you all provided, I was able to do additional research and find the 3rd book of the series listed as "The Wizard's Mirror".  It was listed as "unpublished" but I could find no information about why it was never published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my good friend Bob Vardeman about this. The very short answer is that the novel is written, but requires editing. The good news is that it's evidently in the pipeline.

> **Q.** *Was there ever a sequel planned for "In the Sea Nymph's Lair"?*
>
> **Bob Vardeman:** *Wizard's Spell Mirror is written. Problem is with me getting it rewritten because so many other projects have popped up.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Twitter - 29 Sep 2016](https://twitter.com/BobV451/status/781549214144663553?lang=en-gb)</sup></sub>

Comment: Are these people really your good friends, or just random people you asked for an answer? :)

Comment: Wow!  That's great.  Between this and your earlier comments, I believe the question is fully answered.

Comment: @Adamant - Completely random people I've contacted on twitter.